# Error : None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied issue in FragmentStateAdapter in viewpager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2, child-fragment, fragmentstateadapter

See my code

I am using viewpager 2 in a fragment to hold child fragments. There can be 'n' number of child fragments. It is showing lint error in adapter.

//See my fragment code

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val docs = mutableListOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

        view_pager.adapter = DocAdapter(childFragmentManager,lifecycle,docs)

    }
```

// my adapter code

```
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
    import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
    import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter
    
    class DocAdapter(fa: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle, private val docs : MutableList<Int>) :
FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int = docs.size
    
        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment = DocUploadFragment().newInstance(docs[position])
    }
```

The lint error is in the following line of the adapter class

```
class DocAdapter(fa: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle, private val docs : MutableList<Int>) :
FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {
```

Answer (score 2):

[`FragmentStateAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter#FragmentStateAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,%20androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle)) requires a `FragmentManager` and `Lifecycle` in its constructor. Change your `DocAdapter` to this:

```
class DocAdapter(fa: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle, private val docs : MutableList<Int>) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fa, lifecycle) {
    ...
}
```